# Masking elements with SVG

Tags: svg, mask, masking, clipping

I have a faux circle (border-radius 50% width&height) that has a bunch of HTML inside of it... Is it possible to create an SVG that will overlay and mask it so that nothing that's inside the circle will touch anything else? I have handles and additional buttons, etc, that attach to the circle interface... Occassionally pieces overlap. I would like the buttons to be masked via SVG as well... I've run into a lot of snags with this concept, and have found it hard to decipher the information that is out there in order to completely fulfill the requirements of the user interface.

aycheteeteepee://jsfiddle.net/ymtV3/

Something to this effect, but imagine the addition of "handles" or "buttons" along the outside edge that become covered as the interface is rotated.  I've come up with various hacks and they work fine, but ideally this would be created properly with the image clipped in accordance.